# С++ При запуске не может найти библиотеки

Tags: c++, linux, qt

Скомплирование и запуск приложение через IDE (QT Creator) происходит успешно. Через консоль, показывает на отсутсвующие библиотеки.

ldd ./ Команда

```
ldd Simulator 
./Simulator: /usr/lib64/libQt5Core.so.5: version `Qt_5.10' not found (required by ./Simulator)
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffdeccd8000)
        glstudioLinux64_gcc_480.so.5.1.2 => not found
        libaudiofile.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libaudiofile.so.1 (0x00007f6fc3f4d000)
        libGeographic.so.17 => not found
        libgobject-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libgobject-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f6fc3cfc000)
        libgmodule-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libgmodule-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f6fc3af8000)
        libgthread-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libgthread-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f6fc38f6000)
        libjpeg.so.8 => /usr/lib64/libjpeg.so.8 (0x00007f6fc368c000)
        libQt5OpenGL.so.5 => /usr/lib64/libQt5OpenGL.so.5 (0x00007f6fc3432000)
        libQt5MultimediaWidgets.so.5 => /usr/lib64/libQt5MultimediaWidgets.so.5 (0x00007f6fc3212000)
        libpulse-mainloop-glib.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libpulse-mainloop-glib.so.0 (0x00007f6fc300d000)
        libpulse.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libpulse.so.0 (0x00007f6fc2dbf000)
        libglib-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f6fc2aaf000)
        libQt5Widgets.so.5 => /usr/lib64/libQt5Widgets.so.5 (0x00007f6fc223b000)
        libQt5Gamepad.so.5 => not found
        libQt5Multimedia.so.5 => /usr/lib64/libQt5Multimedia.so.5 (0x00007f6fc1f2a000)
        libQt5Gui.so.5 => /usr/lib64/libQt5Gui.so.5 (0x00007f6fc17db000)
        libQt5Network.so.5 => /usr/lib64/libQt5Network.so.5 (0x00007f6fc1484000)
        libQt5Core.so.5 => /usr/lib64/libQt5Core.so.5 (0x00007f6fc0dc5000)
        libGL.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libGL.so.1 (0x00007f6fc0b59000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f6fc093c000)
        libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f6fc05b3000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007f6fc02b6000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f6fc009f000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f6fbfcfc000)
        libFLAC.so.8 => /usr/lib64/libFLAC.so.8 (0x00007f6fbfac5000)
        libffi.so.4 => /usr/lib64/libffi.so.4 (0x00007f6fbf8bc000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f6fbf6b8000)
        libpulsecommon-9.0.so => /usr/lib64/pulseaudio/libpulsecommon-9.0.so (0x00007f6fbf43a000)
        libjson-c.so.2 => /usr/lib64/libjson-c.so.2 (0x00007f6fbf22f000)
        libdbus-1.so.3 => /lib64/libdbus-1.so.3 (0x00007f6fbefe8000)
        libpcre.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libpcre.so.1 (0x00007f6fbed79000)
        libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libX11.so.6 (0x00007f6fbea3b000)
        libharfbuzz.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libharfbuzz.so.0 (0x00007f6fbe7ac000)
        libz.so.1 => /lib64/libz.so.1 (0x00007f6fbe596000)
        libpng16.so.16 => /usr/lib64/libpng16.so.16 (0x00007f6fbe359000)
        libssl.so.1.0.0 => /lib64/libssl.so.1.0.0 (0x00007f6fbe0ee000)
        libcrypto.so.1.0.0 => /lib64/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 (0x00007f6fbdc95000)
        libicui18n.so.52.1 => /usr/lib64/libicui18n.so.52.1 (0x00007f6fbd881000)
        libicuuc.so.52.1 => /usr/lib64/libicuuc.so.52.1 (0x00007f6fbd502000)
        libpcre16.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libpcre16.so.0 (0x00007f6fbd29c000)
        librt.so.1 => /lib64/librt.so.1 (0x00007f6fbd094000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f6fc4188000)
        libexpat.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libexpat.so.1 (0x00007f6fbce6a000)
        libxcb-dri3.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libxcb-dri3.so.0 (0x00007f6fbcc67000)
        libxcb-present.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libxcb-present.so.0 (0x00007f6fbca64000)
        libxcb-sync.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libxcb-sync.so.1 (0x00007f6fbc85e000)
        libxshmfence.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libxshmfence.so.1 (0x00007f6fbc65b000)
        libglapi.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libglapi.so.0 (0x00007f6fbc42c000)
        libXext.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libXext.so.6 (0x00007f6fbc21a000)
        libXdamage.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libXdamage.so.1 (0x00007f6fbc017000)
        libXfixes.so.3 => /usr/lib64/libXfixes.so.3 (0x00007f6fbbe11000)
        libX11-xcb.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libX11-xcb.so.1 (0x00007f6fbbc0f000)
        libxcb-glx.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libxcb-glx.so.0 (0x00007f6fbb9f7000)
        libxcb-dri2.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libxcb-dri2.so.0 (0x00007f6fbb7f2000)
        libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libxcb.so.1 (0x00007f6fbb5d2000)
        libXxf86vm.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libXxf86vm.so.1 (0x00007f6fbb3cc000)
        libdrm.so.2 => /usr/lib64/libdrm.so.2 (0x00007f6fbb1bb000)
        libogg.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libogg.so.0 (0x00007f6fbafb4000)
        libsystemd.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libsystemd.so.0 (0x00007f6fbad2d000)
        libsndfile.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libsndfile.so.1 (0x00007f6fbaac2000)
        libfreetype.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libfreetype.so.6 (0x00007f6fba825000)
        libgraphite2.so.3 => /usr/lib64/libgraphite2.so.3 (0x00007f6fba5fd000)
        libicudata.so.52.1 => /usr/lib64/libicudata.so.52.1 (0x00007f6fba3fc000)
        libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libXau.so.6 (0x00007f6fba1f8000)
        libselinux.so.1 => /lib64/libselinux.so.1 (0x00007f6fb9fd2000)
        libcap.so.2 => /lib64/libcap.so.2 (0x00007f6fb9dcd000)
        libresolv.so.2 => /lib64/libresolv.so.2 (0x00007f6fb9bb6000)
        liblzma.so.5 => /usr/lib64/liblzma.so.5 (0x00007f6fb998d000)
        libgcrypt.so.20 => /usr/lib64/libgcrypt.so.20 (0x00007f6fb96a7000)
        libgpg-error.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libgpg-error.so.0 (0x00007f6fb9492000)
        libvorbisenc.so.2 => /usr/lib64/libvorbisenc.so.2 (0x00007f6fb8fc3000)
        libspeex.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libspeex.so.1 (0x00007f6fb8daa000)
        libbz2.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libbz2.so.1 (0x00007f6fb8b9b000)
        libvorbis.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libvorbis.so.0 (0x00007f6fb896d000)
```

И вот мой про файл.

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2017-09-19T12:26:24
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core gui network opengl gamepad multimedia multimediawidgets

#greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = Simulator
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG+= static

# The following define makes your compiler emit warnings if you use
# any feature of Qt which has been marked as deprecated (the exact warnings
# depend on your compiler). Please consult the documentation of the
# deprecated API in order to know how to port your code away from it.
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS
# You can also make your code fail to compile if you use deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
# You can also select to disable deprecated APIs only up to a certain version of Qt.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0

INCLUDEPATH += "$$/home/devsuse/glstudio/include" \ #for GL STUDIO
    "$$/home/devsuse/glstudio/plugins/include" #for GL STUDIO

LIBS += -L"$$/home/devsuse/glstudio/lib" #for GL STUDIO
LIBS += -L"$$/home/devsuse/glstudio/plugins/lib" #for GL STUDIO
LIBS += -L"/usr/local/lib"

DEFINES += "GLS_IMPORT_LIBRARY" #for GL STUDIO
DEFINES += "LINUX"
#DEFINES += EST_PEAK_NO_LIB_EXPORT

LIBS += -lglstudioLinux64_gcc_480 #for GL STUDIO glstudioLinux64_gcc_480.so.5.1.2
LIBS += -lgls_3d_cable_Linux64_gcc_480 #for GL STUDIO
LIBS += -lgls_advanced_mesh_Linux64_gcc_480 #for GL STUDIO
LIBS += -lgls_dynamic_path_Linux64_gcc_480 #for GL STUDIO
LIBS += -lgls_multi_view_Linux64_gcc_480 #for GL STUDIO
LIBS += -lgls_odometer_Linux64_gcc_480 #for GL STUDIO
LIBS += -lgls_nine_patch_Linux64_gcc_480 #for GL STUDIO
LIBS += -laudiofile #for GL STUDIO
LIBS += -lgls_map_aif_Linux64_gcc_480 #for GL STUDIO
LIBS += -lgls_map_cadrg_Linux64_gcc_480 #for GL STUDIO
LIBS += -lgls_map_dnc_Linux64_gcc_480 #for GL STUDIO
LIBS += -lgls_map_dted_Linux64_gcc_480 #for GL STUDIO
LIBS += -lgls_map_geotiff_Linux64_gcc_480 #for GL STUDIO
LIBS += -lgls_map_toolkit_Linux64_gcc_480 #for GL STUDIO
LIBS += -lgls_text_box_Linux64_gcc_480 #for GL STUDIO
LIBS += -lGeographic
LIBS += -lglib-2.0
LIBS += -lgobject-2.0
LIBS += -lgmodule-2.0
LIBS += -lgthread-2.0
LIBS += -ljpeg

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/ #for GL STUDIO
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/ #for GL STUDIO
INCLUDEPATH += /usr/include/gstreamer-1.0
INCLUDEPATH += /usr/include/glib-2.0/
INCLUDEPATH += /usr/lib64/glib-2.0/include/

PKGCONFIG += GStreamer-1.0
PKGCONFIG += gstreamer-1.0 gstreamer-1.0-app

FORMS += \
    downlink.ui \
    flugdialog.ui \
    mainwindow.ui \
    uplink.ui



HEADERS += \
    GLMap/MapView.h \
    GLMap/waypoints.h \
    GLMap/xmlreader.h \
    GLMap/pugixml.hpp \
    GLMap/pugiconfig.hpp \
    GLMap/waypointdata.h \
    aladinclient.h \
    aladinlib.h \
    aladintypes.h \
    aladintypesfunctions.h \
    aladintypesmeta.h \
    aladintypessupport.h \
    downlink.h \
    flugdialog.h \
    global.h \
    mainwindow.h \
    minimalaladinclient.h \
    qglsrso.h \
    uplink.h \
    GeographicLib/Accumulator.hpp \
    GeographicLib/AlbersEqualArea.hpp \
    GeographicLib/AzimuthalEquidistant.hpp \
    GeographicLib/CassiniSoldner.hpp \
    GeographicLib/CircularEngine.hpp \
    GeographicLib/Config.h \
    GeographicLib/Constants.hpp \
    GeographicLib/DMS.hpp \
    GeographicLib/Ellipsoid.hpp \
    GeographicLib/EllipticFunction.hpp \
    GeographicLib/GARS.hpp \
    GeographicLib/Geocentric.hpp \
    GeographicLib/GeoCoords.hpp \
    GeographicLib/Geodesic.hpp \
    GeographicLib/GeodesicExact.hpp \
    GeographicLib/GeodesicLine.hpp \
    GeographicLib/GeodesicLineExact.hpp \
    GeographicLib/Geohash.hpp \
    GeographicLib/Geoid.hpp \
    GeographicLib/Georef.hpp \
    GeographicLib/Gnomonic.hpp \
    GeographicLib/GravityCircle.hpp \
    GeographicLib/GravityModel.hpp \
    GeographicLib/LambertConformalConic.hpp \
    GeographicLib/LocalCartesian.hpp \
    GeographicLib/MagneticCircle.hpp \
    GeographicLib/MagneticModel.hpp \
    GeographicLib/Math.hpp \
    GeographicLib/MGRS.hpp \
    GeographicLib/NearestNeighbor.hpp \
    GeographicLib/NormalGravity.hpp \
    GeographicLib/OSGB.hpp \
    GeographicLib/PolarStereographic.hpp \
    GeographicLib/PolygonArea.hpp \
    GeographicLib/Rhumb.hpp \
    GeographicLib/SphericalEngine.hpp \
    GeographicLib/SphericalHarmonic.hpp \
    GeographicLib/SphericalHarmonic1.hpp \
    GeographicLib/SphericalHarmonic2.hpp \
    GeographicLib/TransverseMercator.hpp \
    GeographicLib/TransverseMercatorExact.hpp \
    GeographicLib/Utility.hpp \
    GeographicLib/UTMUPS.hpp \
    gamepadmonitor.h

SOURCES += \
    GLMap/MapView.cpp \
    GLMap/waypoints.cpp \
    GLMap/xmlreader.cpp \
    GLMap/pugixml.cpp \
    aladinclient.cpp \
    aladintypesmeta.cpp \
    downlink.cpp \
    flugdialog.cpp \
    main.cpp \
    mainwindow.cpp \
    minimalaladinclient.cpp \
    qglsrso.cpp \
    uplink.cpp \
    gamepadmonitor.cpp

RESOURCES += \
    ui_design.qrc
```

Возможно кому-то покажется, что это является дубликатом моего прошлого вопроса, но нет.

Еще заметил, что Qt добавляет в свой `RUN` - `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`
Qt собран с флагом `-static` и установлен. Запусть приложение хочу на другом компьюторе, без устанволки всех библиотек и тд.

Comment: Для того, что линковщик знал, откуда брать динамические библиотеки для запуска исполняемого файла, необходимо, чтобы эти библиотеки находились в стандартных путях, либо чтобы был установлен `rpath` в исполняемом файле.

Comment: Также вы неправильно линкуете Qt. Если вы хотите линковать его статически, почитайте как это правильно сделать вот [тут](http://doc.qt.io/QtForDeviceCreation/qtee-static-linking.html).

Comment: @Ternvein а что значит я не правильно линкую Qt? В какой строчке ошибка?

Comment: Во многих. Почитайте статью по ссылке. Конкретно у вас как минимум не заданы `QtPlugins` для статической линковки.
Вы просто можете посмотреть на приложенный вами вывод `ldd`, чтобы увидеть, что все библиотеки Qt слинкованы динамически.

Comment: @Ternvein я уже смотрел ту статью и еще одну про установку -static Qt. Как и сделал. Но, в той что вы скинули, говорится о плагинах связаных с QML

Comment: Про QML говорится ниже, смотрите в *Building static application*. Вот вам конкретная [ссылка](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/plugins-howto.html#static-plugins) на статическую линковку плагинов.

Comment: @Ternvein все равно немного не пойму попробовав. Желательно было бы запихать все в .qrc и оттуда уже искать.